# Configuring Jenkins plugins with Puppet

Tags: jenkins, puppet

I'm using the rtyler/jenkins Puppet module to deploy my Jenkins instance. One thing I can't seem to find documentation on is how to use Puppet to configure the Jenkins plugins once I've installed them. Can someone point me to some documentation and/or write a quick example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in how to pull this off, I'm using the Jenkins SCM plugin available here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin

This requires manually setting up Jenkins and having the plugin sync all the configuration settings to a repository. All future Jenkins instances provisioned by Puppet will need to have all the necessary plugins installed, but the SCM plugin will automatically download all the necessary settings. However, do note that some of the plugins will require you to manually add includes into the SCM to begin tracking them: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+Config+shared+additionnal+includes

Answer (score 1):

the module he provides is only for managing/configuring jenkins and managing plugins. All plugins are vastly different, there is no possibility his scripts would be able to manage the wide breadth of jenkins plugins out there. You would want to try to capture that using jenkins backups or by looking into how each module allows configuration.